# java string new line not working when sending with email

Tags: java, email, apache-axis

Let's say I want to send an email using `org.apache.axis.client.Call` and the body message of the mail has a format like :

```
bodyMsg="Name:Justin\nSurname:Biber\nPosition:artist\nField1:1234\nField2:eqweq";
```

but when I receive the mail there is no the new line for each field. For example, I want to receive :

```
    Name:Justin
    Surname:Biber
    Position:artist
    Field1:1234
    Field2:eqweq
```

and I am receiving this :

```
Name:Justin Surname:BiberPosition:artist Field1:1234 Field2:eqweq
```

A snippet of my code is something like that :

```
    org.apache.axis.client.Call _call = createCall();
        _call.setOperation(_operations[0]);
        _call.setUseSOAPAction(true);
        _call.setSOAPActionURI("");
        _call.setEncodingStyle(null);
        _call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.client.Call.SEND_TYPE_ATTR, Boolean.FALSE);
        _call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.PROP_DOMULTIREFS, Boolean.FALSE);
        _call.setSOAPVersion(org.apache.axis.soap.SOAPConstants.SOAP11_CONSTANTS);
        _call.setOperationName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://example.com/", "createEmail"));

        setRequestHeaders(_call);
        setAttachments(_call);
 try {        java.lang.Object _resp = _call.invoke(new java.lang.Object[] {new java.lang.Long(arg0), arg1, arg2, bodyMsg});
 } catch(Exception ex) {}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Try to send `\r\n` instead of `\n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you to try the following things.

If you are reading this email on Windows probably you should send `\r\n` instead of `\n`, i.e. system property `line.separator`.

If you are reading this email as HTML probably you should send the HTML newline tag `<br/>`.

Comment: With <br/> it's ok. Thanks!

Comment: No, SMS is different. The SMS viewer is typically very simple and I doubt that it supports HTML tags. The SMS viewer are very different and platform specific. Typically people tend to avoid any special characters into SMS. Try `\n` however. Probably it will work, but I am not sure. Moreover this may depend on the sending technique. Probably `\n` will be removed or corrupted by your client.